# MS Excel : changing the counter in formula to some other than the one Excel has assumed

Tags: excel, excel-formula, counter, formula-editor

An excel formula looks like this

```
=", " &($C$1)+1
```

Here's how the data looks  when I paste special --> forumulas

```
    1
, 2
, 3
, 3
```

I want it to increase the LAST Number +1 in the counter . 
Something like

```
    1
, 2
, 3
, 4
```

I can of course fix it many "work-around" ways like having 1 more column for the step up counter and then using it in the formula. Here Excel BY  DEFAULT will step up the counter on Column C1 like this

```
 =", " &(C1)+1
```

and increase C1 to C2 C3 ..Cn  on a  "paste special" ..unless you freeze it with $C$1 but then it's not sensible enough to consider the last +1 as the counter and use that. So the counter remains the same and the value is the same.
How to tell excel to use the last + 1 as the counter

Comment: Maybe `=", " & SUBSTITUTE(C1,", ","")+1`

Comment: You could use `=", " & row()-1+$C$1`

Comment: Both of 'em work . Pl present as answers. I will tick  one off. TY

Comment: answer = changenow (scott.comment) : )

Comment: change this into answer and I will vote up .I voted up every answer I got . If you think this was a  good question worth some wits ..you could do the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe

```
=", " & SUBSTITUTE(C1,", ","")+1
```

Comment: I voted up every answer I got . If you think this was a  good question worth some wits ..you could do the same

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your first formula is in A1 you can use:

```
=", "&($C$1)+(1-ROW($A$1)+ROW(A1))
```

When you copy down, the original `ROW($A$1)` will stay the same while the second `ROW(A1)` will change with your copy range. Cheers,

Comment: Yes, but I don't know where the location of the first cell in the range he's placing the formulas in. Might be `A1` but might be `ZZ13`. Your formula is shorter but at the expense of only being applicable to a small subset of possible scenarios. From the OP description I didn't want to assume where the formula was going to be copied to. Regards.

Comment: Scott - yes I noticed that. Thanks Nbayly. I wish there was a share credit concept for 1 answer - I be doing that. Thank You folks. ( though I voted up everyone who  commented )

Comment: I voted up every answer I got . If you think this was a  good question worth some wits ..you could do the same